# Application of optional sampling theorem in a proof of the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequalitiy

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

[image]

(Doob's optional sampling theorem ):Let $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ be a right continuous martingale and $\tau \text{ and} \sigma $ be two stopping times such that $\sigma \leq \tau$ a.s. If we assume that one of the following conditions hold

1. $X$ is closed
2. $\tau$ is bounded

Then $X_{\tau}$,$X_{\sigma} \in L^1$ and 
$E[X_{\tau} \mid \mathbb{F}_{\sigma}]=X_{\sigma}$.

I don't see why the above theorem implies the last statement in the attached picture. Can you please give me a hint why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the first formula of the proof gives

$$|M_t|^q = \underbrace{\int_0^t q \, \text{sgn}(M_s) |M_s|^{q-1} \, dM_s}_{=:X_t} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} q (q-1) \int_0^t |M_s|^{q-2} d\langle M \rangle_s}_{=:A_t}. \tag{1}$$

Since $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale with continuous sample paths, we know that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale with continuous sample paths. Define a sequence of stopping times by

$$\sigma_n := \inf\{t \geq 0; |M_t| \geq n\}.$$

Then, $\sigma_n \uparrow \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, $|M_{t \wedge \sigma_n}| \leq n$, and therefore it is not difficult to see that $(\sigma_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a localizing sequence for $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ (i.e. $(X_{t \wedge \sigma_n})_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$). As $\tau$ is a bounded stopping time, Doob's optional stopping theorem yields

$$\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_0) = X_0 = 0. \tag{2}$$

Applying Fatous lemma, we obtain

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(|M_{\tau}|^q \mid \mathcal{F}_0) &= \mathbb{E} \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} |M_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}|^q \mid \mathcal{F}_0 \right) \\ &\leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|M_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}|^q \mid \mathcal{F}_0) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \liminf_{n \to \infty} \left( \mathbb{E}(X_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_0) + \mathbb{E}(A_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_0)  \right) \\ &\stackrel{(2)}{=} \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(A_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_0) . \end{align*}$$

Finally, we can apply the monotone convergence theorem to conclude that

$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(A_{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_0) = \frac{1}{2} q(q-1) \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{\tau} |M_t|^{q-2} \, d\langle M \rangle_t \mid \mathcal{F}_0 \right).$$

Combining both calculations finishes the proof.

Comment: From the assumption, $M_t$ is a local martingale. Why do you assume it is martingale?

Comment: @Gordon Ah, I missed that; sorry... actually, it doesn't really make a difference, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @saz I was reading your proof again,$A_t$ is increasing because $C_t=\langle M \rangle_t$ is an increasing process and therefore for all $\omega$ we have that $C_t(\omega)  \geq C_s)\omega)$ and therefore $dC$ is always positive for all $\omega$ and the integrand is positive and therefore we can conclude that $A_t$ is an increasing in $t$ for all $\omega$ and therefore an increasing process. My argument is valid?

Comment: @user3503589 The statement "$dC$ is always positive" doesn't make sense, but basically your argumentation is correct. $C_t$ is increasing and therefore $t \mapsto \int_0^t f(s) \, dC_s$ is increasing for any non-negative function $f$. This gives that $A_t$ is increasing (in $t$).

Comment: @saz Isn't there a typo in equation (1), shouldn't it be $|M_t|^q=$ and if that is the case $|M_t|^q$ is not a local martingale(though it has almost surely continuous paths) and we cannot say anything about $X_t$?

Comment: @user3503589 Yeah, it should be $|M_t|^q$. Why can't we say anything about $X_t$? It is still a stochastic integral with respect to a martingale; hence a (local) martingale.

Comment: @saz my bad. I was just correcting my comment . You mean a stochastic integral with respect to a local martingale right? And I do not have to show that the integrand belongs to $\Lambda^2_{loc?}$

Comment: @user3503589 Yes, you have to show this... but since $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, that's not dfficitult to show. Just define $$\tau_n := \inf\{t \geq 0; |M_t| \geq n\},$$ then $|M_{t \wedge \tau_n}| \leq n$ and it follows easily that the (stopped) integrand is square integrable

Comment: Thank you saz, I understand now